# How to upload video on YouTube with Ruby

Tags: ruby, upload, youtube, gdata

I am trying to upload a youtube video using the GData gem (I have seen the youtube_g gem but would like to make it work with pure GData if possible), but I keep getting this error:

GData::Client::BadRequestError in 'MyProject::Google::YouTube should upload the actual video to youtube (once it does, mock this test out)'
request error 400: No file found in upload request.

I am using this code:

```
def metadata
  data = <<-EOF
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<entry xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2005/Atom"
  xmlns:media="http://search.yahoo.com/mrss/"
  xmlns:yt="http://gdata.youtube.com/schemas/2007">
  <media:group>
    <media:title type="plain">Bad Wedding Toast</media:title>
    <media:description type="plain">
      I gave a bad toast at my friend's wedding.
    </media:description>
    <media:category scheme="http://gdata.youtube.com/schemas/2007/categories.cat">People</media:category>
    <media:keywords>toast, wedding</media:keywords>
  </media:group>
</entry>
EOF
end

@yt = GData::Client::YouTube.new
@yt.clientlogin("name", "pass")
@yt.developer_key = "myKey"
url = "http://uploads.gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/users/name/uploads"
mime_type = "multipart/related"
file_path = "sample_upload.mp4"
@yt.post_file(url, file_path, mime_type, metadata)
```

What is the recommended/standard way for uploading videos to youtube with ruby, what is your method?

## Update

After applying the changes to `wrapped_entry`, the string it produces looks like this:

```
--END_OF_PART_59003
Content-Type: application/atom+xml; charset=UTF-8
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<entry xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2005/Atom"
  xmlns:media="http://search.yahoo.com/mrss/"
  xmlns:yt="http://gdata.youtube.com/schemas/2007">
  <media:group>
    <media:title type="plain">Bad Wedding Toast</media:title>
    <media:description type="plain">
      I gave a bad toast at my friend's wedding.
    </media:description>
    <media:category scheme="http://gdata.youtube.com/schemas/2007/categories.cat">People</media:category>
    <media:keywords>toast, wedding</media:keywords>
  </media:group>
</entry>

--END_OF_PART_59003
Content-Type: multipart/related
Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary
```

... and inspecting the request and response looks like this:

Request:

```
<GData::HTTP::Request:0x1b8bb44 @method=:post
@url="http://uploads.gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/users/lancejpollard/uploads"
@body=#<GData::HTTP::MimeBody:0x1b8c738 @parts=[#<GData::HTTP::MimeBodyString:0x1b8c058 @bytes_read=0
@string="--END_OF_PART_30909\r\nContent-Type: application/atom+xml; charset=UTF-8\r\n\r\n
<?xml version=\"1.0\"?>\n<entry xmlns=\"http://www.w3.org/2005/Atom\"\n  xmlns:media=\"http://search.yahoo.com/mrss/\"\n  xmlns:yt=\"http://gdata.youtube.com/schemas/2007\">\n  <media:group>\n    <media:title type=\"plain\">Bad Wedding Toast</media:title>\n    <media:description type=\"plain\">\n      I gave a bad toast at my friend's wedding.\n    </media:description>\n    <media:category scheme=\"http://gdata.youtube.com/schemas/2007/categories.cat\">People</media:category>\n    <media:keywords>toast
wedding</media:keywords>\n  </media:group>\n</entry>
\n\r\n--END_OF_PART_30909\r\nContent-Type: multipart/related\r\nContent-Transfer-Encoding: binary\r\n\r\n">
#<File:/Users/Lance/Documents/Development/git/thing/spec/fixtures/sample_upload.mp4>
#<GData::HTTP::MimeBodyString:0x1b8c044 @bytes_read=0
@string="\r\n--END_OF_PART_30909--">]
@current_part=0
@boundary="END_OF_PART_30909">
@headers={"Slug"=>"sample_upload.mp4"
"User-Agent"=>"GoogleDataRubyUtil-AnonymousApp"
"GData-Version"=>"2"
"X-GData-Key"=>"key=AI39si7jkhs_ECjF4unOQz8gpWGSKXgq0KJpm8wywkvBSw4s8oJd5p5vkpvURHBNh-hiYJtoKwQqSfot7KoCkeCE32rNcZqMxA"
"Content-Type"=>"multipart/related; boundary=\"END_OF_PART_30909\""
"MIME-Version"=>"1.0"}>
```

Response:

```
#<GData::HTTP::Response:0x1b897e0 @body="No file found in upload request."
@headers={"cache-control"=>"no-cache
no-store
must-revalidate"
"connection"=>"close"
"expires"=>"Fri
01 Jan 1990 00:00:00 GMT"
"content-type"=>"text/plain; charset=utf-8"
"date"=>"Fri
11 Dec 2009 02:10:25 GMT"
"server"=>"Upload Server Built on Nov 30 2009 13:21:18 (1259616078)"
"x-xss-protection"=>"0"
"content-length"=>"32"
"pragma"=>"no-cache"}
@status_code=400>
```

Still not working, I'll have to check it out more with those changes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure if you ever fixed this, but I believe the `mime_type` param in `post_file` should be set to the mime_type of the **video** - you've got it set to "multipart/related" in your sample code.

Comment: haven't gotten around to getting it to work, I hope this fixes it! thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I apologize for just linking but I think this may help out [linky](http://www.ruby-forum.com/topic/152849#680706)

Comment: I saw that one, thanks.  I feel like the ruby gdata library handles this already somehow...  Still haven't figured it out.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem with gdata gem.

This fixed it for me.

C:\Ruby\lib\ruby\gems\1.8\gems\gdata-1.1.1\lib\gdata\http

In "class MimeBody" replace "wrap_entry" with this code to fix it.

"def wrap_entry(entry, file_mime_type)
        wrapped_entry = "--#{@boundary}\r\n"
        wrapped_entry += "Content-Type: application/atom+xml;
charset=UTF-8\r\n\r\n"
        wrapped_entry += entry
        wrapped_entry += "\r\n--#{@boundary}\r\n"
        wrapped_entry += "Content-Type: #{file_mime_type}\r\n"
        wrapped_entry += "Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary\r\n\r\n"
        return MimeBodyString.new(wrapped_entry)
      end"

Comment: My code look like this if it helps
@yt = GData::Client::YouTube.new
@yt.clientlogin("name", "pass")
@yt.developer_key = "myKey"
url = 'http://uploads.gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/users/default/uploads'


mime_type = "video/mp4"
file_path = "test.mp4"
response = @yt.post_file(url, file_path, mime_type, metadata).to_xml