# How to upload video to YouTube via Ruby?

Tags: ruby, upload, youtube

I need to upload video files from my computer to youtube automatically, I use ruby.

I tried `gem youtube_it` - I have error `YouTubeIt::AuthenticationError: BadAuthentication` - my actions:

```
client = YouTubeIt::Client.new(:username => "email@gmail.com", :password =>  "my_passwd", :dev_key => "developer_key")
client.video_upload(File.open("file_from_drive"), :title => "test",:description => 'test')
```

Also I tested manually upload video from my `email@gmail.com my_passwd` Google account - I works well. Dev_key I got here - http://code.google.com/apis/youtube/dashboard

Then I tried `gem gdata` as here - [How to upload video on YouTube with Ruby](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1692643/how-to-upload-video-on-youtube-with-ruby)

```
require 'gdata'
yt = GData::Client::YouTube.new
yt.clientlogin("email@gmail.com", "my_passwd")
```

It raises error

`GData::Client::AuthorizationError: request error 403: Error=BadAuthentication
 Info=WebLoginRequired`

So, How should I automatically upload video? Maybe problem is in my google account?

Comment: ``error 403: Error=BadAuthentication`` tends to mean you are not authenticating properly.

Comment: This looks lie an OAuth error - if you are using an API that signs in as a user  and integrates with the browser, then you must collect a temporary auth token for your app via the web interface.